# How to change the format of a past timestamp

Tags: timestamps

I've got an arbitrary time stamp `1427792481` I'm trying to implement `+"%F"`
so I just get `2015-03-31` How can I do this? My ideal goal would be to get `20150331`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
date -d @1427792481 +"%F"
```

or for 20150331:

```
date -d @1427792481 +"%Y%m%d"
```

Answer (score 3):

> My ideal goal would be to get 20150331

```
date -d @1427792481 +"%Y%m%d"
```

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

- `ksh93` or recent `bash`, any system (shell builtin):

  ```
  printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" 1427792481
  ```
- `zsh` any system (builtin):

  ```
  zmodload zsh/datetime
  strftime %Y%m%d 1427792481
  ```
- GNU `date`:

  ```
  date -d@1427792481 +%Y%m%d
  ```
- GNU `awk`:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%Y%m%d", 1427792481)}'
  ```
- `perl`:

  ```
  perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime 1427792481'
  ```